# survival packages in R that allow for time dependent covariates

Tags: r, survival

Which survival packages in R explicitly allow for time dependent covariates?

By explicitly, I mean that the package allows its models to accept a survival object with the form

```
Surv(start,stop,event)~....
```

For example, the cox proportional hazards model with time dependent covariates has the form:

```
coxph(Surv(start, stop, arrest.time) ~ fin + age + age:stop + prio, data=Rossi.2)
```

I would like to identify packages with more powerful models that accept this form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more powerful model to achieve this, is a relatively new methodology that has been proposed by [Wulfsohn and Tsiatis, 1997](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2533118?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104540804847) (see also an important contribution from [Henderson, Diggle and Dobson, 2000](http://biostatistics.oxfordjournals.org/content/1/4/465.short)) is the **Joint modelling of longitudinal and survival data**.

The model consists of two parts, the longitudinal submodel:

$$ y_i(t_{ij}) = W_i(t_{ij}) + e_{ij} ~~~, e \sim \text{N}(0,\sigma_e^2)$$

with $ W_i(t_{ij}) = x_i'(t_{ij}) \beta + z_i'(t_{ij}) b_i + u_i \delta $

and the survival submodel:

$$ h_i(T_i) = h_0(T_i) \exp(\alpha W_i(T_i) + \phi v_i) $$

with $W_i(T_i) = \beta_{0i} + \beta_{1i} T_i + \delta u_i$

and the estimation is conducted via the joint likelihood. The motivation of this method is exactly what you need, to fit survival models with time-dependent covariates.

There are two packages in CRAN, the `JM` and the `joineR`, my preference is the first one, mainly due to its documentation. You can investigate further to see the modifications or options you may need for your problem.

Comment: The JM package looks fascinating. I'm primarily concerned with predictive accuracy, not interpreting the covariates.  I wonder if the submodels could be swapped out for more powerful algorithms, like random forests.

Comment: I've actually built my own solution from scratch to these types of problems, it'll be interesting to see how JM models compare.

Comment: I don't know about random forests, but if you have built these models from scratch, you definitely know how to work on extending things further. Have a look at recent papers for applications, etc.